# search for a number in a JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json array something like

```
[
    { value: 1, hidden: false },
    { value: 2, hidden: false },
    { value: 3, hidden: false }
]
```

I want to see if integer 2 exists in this array. What's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think we both know that "nobody" is a high overestimation. Simple questions with no attempt and no research shown, that just ask for simple code routinely get multiple answers. In fact, an answer was posted 8 seconds after your comment.

Comment: "What is the *best* way?" that largely depends on where the data comes from/what you know about it. For example, if it is always sorted you can do much better with binary search...etc

Comment: There isn't any JSON in the code you posted. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It is a string, not an array. In order to use it, it has to be parsed to get back a data structure similar to the one used to create it. The code you posted shows an array that contains three objects. No JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your environment supports it, and also that you're interested in the other properties of the object, I'd use `Array.prototype.find`:

```
var target = array.find(x => x.value === 2)

if (target.hidden) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of integers, then [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to find the integer in question:

```js
var twoIsInArray = [{value: 1, hidden: false},
{value: 2, hidden: false},
{value: 3, hidden: false}].map(function(entry) {return entry.value;}).includes(2);
console.log({twoIsInArray: twoIsInArray});
```